# I have 200Gb of files in CachedIcons folder. Can I remove them? C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Secure\Icons\CachedIcons\data\

Tags: windows-7, windows

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Secure\Icons\CachedIcons\data\

This folder contains about 500 folders named like "0f0ba4c4f7e6644d21e4275bceedd939" and contains a

- .nfo: with a name of a random movie or random program
- .avi(sometimes): With the same name as the .nfo file and is corrupted
- .exe: with a 12mb executable file that crashes
- .dat(sometimes): usualy called setup.dat

A lot of folders have the exact same file size (812MB), The names of the movies/programs are many of those I haven't even ever seen before.

The folder is also listed as a system folder. 
I would think this has been some kind of virus that has done this.

Can I remove all the data from the folder?

Comment: I don't have the Secure folder on any of my W7 systems, if you suspect malware, remove that first, then delete the folder.

Comment: If the data is being generated by a malicious infection.  You would need to delete the virus before you wiped the contents of the directory.

Comment: I would then just remove the files if you don't have them at all. I ran an anti-virus scan on the files in the folder though, but they weren't detected as malware. @Ramhound.

Comment: I'm also asking because I once deleted files from another system folder (Windows/Installer) like 80GB for space and it broke my pc ;p

Comment: The files in question are not used by Windows nor generated by Windows.  The only search results on that particular folder are connected to a virus.

Comment: This might be the work of a virus. See this translation of a [post](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.drweb.com%2Findex.php%3Fshowtopic%3D319196) from Russian to English.